# How shall I concatenate the elements of a list so that the outcome is pairs of the elements?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, concatenation

I have a a list [a, b, c]. I would like to make pairs of the elements of the list (ab, ac, bc), but I do not need aa, bb, cc. And I also don't need ca, if I have ac.
This is the try:

```
    list = ["a","b","c"]
    x = 0
    y = x + 1
    while len(list) > y:
        p1 = l[x]
        p2 = l[y]
        z = p1 + p2
        print(z)
        y = y + 1
        while len(list) > x+1:
            x = x + 1
        print(z)
```

This code gives the ab, ab, cc, cc outcome.
The expected outcome would be:
ab
ac
bc.
Thanks for the suggestions in advance.
1XY0

Comment: Those are just combinations. I suggest : ```[''.join(i for i in comb) for comb in itertools.combinations(['a','b','c'],2)]```

Comment: And one more question. Is while-looping the smart way to do this? Is there an alternative (meaning: better) tool in Python?

Comment: @Sujay, thank you very much. I guess you answered the supplementary question too. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get all combinations, then no. If no, then you can use a while loop to get consecutive elements

Comment: Most welcome. Consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for you:

```
l = ["a","b","c","d"]
x = 0
y = x + 1
l1 = []
while x < len(l)-1:
    l1.append(l[x]+l[y])
    y += 1

    if y == len(l):
        x += 1
        y = x+1
        
print (" ".join(l1))
```

Output:

```
ab ac ad bc bd cd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just go with `itertools.combinations`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(i for i in comb) for comb in itertools.combinations(['a','b','c'],2)]
['ab', 'ac', 'bc']
```

---

A little improvement:

1. if `len(l)` is equal to `y`, set `y` as 0, so that it can fetch the first element of `l` when `x` is at the last element.
2. if `len(x)` is equal to `x`, break out of the loop.
3. Use `print()` only once. In your code, you are using it twice.
4. Remove the second `while` loop. No need for that

```
l = ["a","b","c"]
x = 0
y = x + 1

while len(l) >= y:

    if y==len(l):
        y=0
    if x == len(l):
        break

    p1 = l[x]
    p2 = l[y]

    z = p1 + p2
    y += 1
    x += 1
    print(z)
```

Output:

```
ab
bc
ca
```